# Glass BSDF shader rendering problem

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders, fluid-simulation, glass

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on fluid simulation. Everything works fine until the rendering. As shown, the viewport render looks well but when trying to render image (F12) the torus roughness appears different.
[image]
[image]

I'm assuming that the problem may be in the Glass BSDF shader, will appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello could you please shate your file?

Comment: Looks like "z-fighting" from overlapping objects. What about this "Boolean" object that is hidden in the viewport but not hidden for render? (see camea icon in the outliner)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the Boolean object. I was sitting there an hour trying to figure this out. You're the best.